# Can anyone tell me what this red stemmed weed is?

Tags: identification, weeds

It is low to the ground and is all over the borders.

[image]

Comment: That's a teeny tiny picture, do you have more, or larger ones?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure it's [*Geranium Lucidum*](http://www.luontoportti.com/suomi/en/kukkakasvit/shining-cranesbill), commonly called Shiny Geranium or Shining Cranesbill.

It's native to some parts of Europe, Asia and Africa, but classified as a noxious weed in various locations of the US, most particularly in the Pacific Northwest. [This](http://www.nwcb.wa.gov/detail.asp?weed=56) page by the Washington Noxious Weed Control Board has more info with a more in depth pdf of their findings from 2008 being found [here](http://www.nwcb.wa.gov/siteFiles/Geranium_lucidum.pdf)

It usually flowers in May/June around where I live, with seeds being readily transferable and commonly with a high viability. They like damp shade.

As far as control goes, young plants can be picked in the spring time before flowering or they can be chemically treated with either something like glyphosate or with something that targets broadleaf plants. I believe that general seed viability is in the 4-5 year range.

Answer (score 2):

As Kevinsky says, photo's too small really, but here's a guess - [*Saxifrage fortunei*](http://www.alpinegardensociety.net/plants/plant-portraits/Saxifraga+fortunei+plant+of+the+month+Nov+/111/) of some variety (something like [*S. fortunei* 'Blackberry and Apple Pie'](http://www.shootgardening.co.uk/plant/saxifraga-blackberry-and-apple-pie-fortunei), though the leaf coloration isn't right for that one) but really need a larger picture.